# Which pattern and substitution for Regex.Replace can replace all space present inside <>?

Tags: c#, json, regex, regex-replace

I have data in a non-standard format which I am trying to convert to intelligible json.

Format is like

```
dataheads@first{
       first_data = <value1@123 value2_456 value3_789>;
       second_data = <<value4_abc_123 value5_ty>>;};
```

I need in this step:

```
first_data = <value1@123,value2_456,value3_789>;
second_data = <<value4_abc_123,value5_ty>>;
```

I tried `Regex.Replace(contents, @"(<.*)\ (.*>)", "$1,$2");` but it only works for a single space between <>. `\S*(\s)\S*` messes up data outside <>. I am not sure why `<\S*(\s)\S*>` doesn't work. As can be seen, there are a lot more substitutions needed to convert to json so have to be careful not to mess the outsides.

Comment: Do you already have a tool/api/etc that understands the current data format?  I'm concerned that we're going to help you shoot yourself in the foot... In particular my suspicion is that `second_data` has a list for it's value -- implying that you'll need a parser to completely accomplish the task

Comment: Is [this](http://www.regexstorm.net/tester?p=+%28%3f%3d%5b%5e%3e%3c%5d*%3e%28%3f!%3e%29%29&i=%3cvalue1%40123+value2_456+value3_789%3e%0d%0a%3c%3cvalue4_abc_123+value5_ty%3e%3e&r=%2c) the expected result? (click on "context")

Comment: @bobblebubble or `(?<=(?<!<)<[^<>]*) (?=[^><]*>(?!>))` [demo](http://www.regexstorm.net/tester?p=%28%3f%3c%3d%28%3f%3c!%3c%29%3c%5b%5e%3c%3e%5d*%29+%28%3f%3d%5b%5e%3e%3c%5d*%3e%28%3f!%3e%29%29&i=%3cvalue1%40123+value2_456+value3_789%3e%0d%0a%3c%3cvalue4_abc_123+value5_ty%3e%3e&r=%2c)

Comment: Was thinking of this too @4th bird! Depending on data might be already enough to just look ahead, but dunno. Certainly that is more accurate what you show!! Myself I'm even unclear about the `second_data`...

Comment: @bobblebubble You could make a post out of it if you want.

Comment: No worries @4th bird! Waiting myself if further detail gets provided, to me it's not clear.  If more answers here that's good isn't it, but thank you!

Comment: @bobblebubble yes that looks correct

Comment: @Gus no, unfortunately there is no such api right now. I did try to talk with the team but hit a wall.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use this regex:

```
@"((?<=<[^>]*)[ ](?=[^>]*>))+"
```

**Explanation**:

`(` - start group

`(?<=<[^>]*)` - look behind for `<` followed by zero or more characters not being `>`

`[ ]` - match a space

`(?=[^>]*>)` -look ahead for zero or more characters not being `>` followed by `>`

`)+` - repeat this group

Simply replace with `,`.

**Update**:

You can secure the matches further, so it requires the hardcoded values before the space, by including them in the look ahead, like this:

```
@"((?<=<[^>]*(@123|_456|_789|_abc_123|_ty))[ ](?=[^>]*>))+");
```

Comment: It matches ++ but note that it has matches in both lines..not sure if that is desired.

Comment: @Thefourthbird: Well, that's intentional, but may be I misunderstand.

Comment: Yes, it's desired to match both. Seems to work in regex checker, trying it in C# code.